# Prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$ if $\int_a ^b f(x)g(x)dx=0 $ for every continuous function $g$ on $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Assume that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Assume also that $\int_a ^b f(x)g(x)dx=0 $ for every function $g$ that is continuous on $[a,b]$. Prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$

**Attempt:** Let $f(x)g(x) =h(x)$.

Then in $  \int_a ^b h(x) dx =0 \implies h(c_g)(b-a)=0 $ for some $c_g \in [a,b]$.

$b \ne a \implies h(c_g)=0 \implies f(c_g)g(c_g)=0 ~\forall g \in \mathcal{C}[a,b] $

Since, $g$ also includes the constant functions , the above result is possible only when $f(c_g)=0.$

How do I proceed to prove that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Actually $c$ depends on $g$ so it can't be the same $c$ for every continuous function $g$. Notice that if $\int_a^bf(t)g(t)dt=0$ for every $g$, then $\int_a^bf(t)^2dt=0$.

Comment: @Bebop Thank you. The area under the square of a function can be $0$ only when the function as a whole is $0$. I am trying an analytical solution for this as well. 

Suppose $\int_a ^b f^2(t) dt =0$. Could you give a hint to move ahead?

Comment: Hint, $f$ is continuous, so what would happen if you had a point $x$ where $f(x)\neq 0$?

Comment: Hint: observe that the function $F:x\mapsto \int_a^xf(t)^2dt$ defined on $[a,b]$ is monotonic.

Comment: @mickep and @Bebop~ thank you for your comments. Got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Take $g = f$, then $g$ is continuous at $[a,b]$ and

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx = 0$$

**Added:** If $f$ is continuous for all $x \in [a,b]$, suppose for a moment that $f(x) \neq 0$ then $f^2(c) > 0$ for some $c \in [a,b]$. This would give

$$\int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)dx > 0$$

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: He didn't say the values are real.  If the values are complex, how about taking $g = \overline{f}$ so that $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)\,dx = \int_a^b |f(x)|^2\,dx$

Comment: On the tag says real-analysis, but yes you correct.